# How do I get back '&' from '&amp;' in xml c#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have an XML save in database, XML contains special characters like `&`, on converting object to XML its convert `&` to `&amp;`. I want to get back `&` from `&amp;` in XML. Please help.

```
private static XmlDocument DeserializeToXmlDocument(String xml)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlDocument));
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
        XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)xs.Deserialize(stringReader);
        stringReader.Close();
        return doc;
    }
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking. Could you try putting together a [mcve] that shows what you're trying to do and what your desired output is?

Comment: Actually we have documents that have lots of attributes so that we made its xml to avoid to create much many columns in the database table. XML created and saved into db no issue, but at the same time some time we have to save & sign in the form of address and XML never accepted it. XML automatically converted & sing to &amp; . My issue is that i want to get back & sign from &amp; in XML, when i deserialize XML.